# Why is list.append() writing over data in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to append some lists to another list in a for loop, but it seems the append method is writing over the previous data of the list.

```
listFil1 = ["R1000", "D940", "L143", "D182", ...]

position1 = [0,0]

position1list = []

for i in range(0, len(listFil1)):
    #Get the move from each list
    move1 = listFil1[i]

    #evaluate position1
    if move1[0] == "R":
        position1[1] += int(move1[1:])
    elif move1[0] == "L":
        position1[1] -= int(move1[1:])
    elif move1[0] == "U":
        position1[0] += int(move1[1:])
    elif move1[0] == "D":
        position1[0] -= int(move1[1:])

    #Append each move, this is where the problem is
    position1list.append(position1)
```

If I'm printing `position1` inside the for loop, I get the expect results for each iteration:
* [0, 1000]
* [-940, 1000]
* [-940, 857]
* [-1122, 857]
* [-1122, -20]
* [-1831, -20]
* [-1831, -273]
* [-1583, -273]
* [-1583, -574]
* [-1149, -574]
* [-1149, 267]
* [-434, 267]
* [-434, 968]
* ...
* [-1966, -12739]
* [-1966, -13333]

But when I print `position1list` at the end, outside of the for loop, I get the right length of data, but every item in the list is equal to the last position1:
[[-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333], [-1966, -13333],...]

Which part of the code is making append write over the whole list ? 
What can I change to get a list of all the positions at the end ?

Comment: Use `position1list.append(position1[:])` to append a shallow copy at each stage. That will break the alaising that you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re appending the same list reference, so they all have the same elements. You should make a shallow copy each time you append:

```
position1list.append(position1.copy())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `position1` object on all iterations and then simply `append`ing multiple references to the same list inside `position1list`. You need to re-declare your list on each iteration to create a unique object.

---

A simple demonstration of your problem is the following:

```py
>>> l = []
>>> a = [l, l]
>>> a
[[], []]
>>> l.append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [1]]
```

As you can see, because we created a list with `l` multiple times, appending to `l` changes the whole `a` list

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the variable `position1` does not contain directly an array, it contains a reference to the array. That means that if you assign the array to another variable, and the modify one of the variables, both will be modified.

Example :

```py
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> b[0] = 0
>>> a
[0, 2]
>>> b
[0, 2]
```

So to deal with this, you should do a copy of your array :

```py
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b[0] = 0
>>> b
[0, 2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
```